# Gson send epmty collection not null

Tags: java, serialization, gson

By default gson ignores empty collections. 
If we set .serializeNulls() gson replaces empty collections by "null". 
But best practice is to send [](empty collection) not null.

Does gson support any feature for this?

Answer (score 1):

> By default gson ignores empty collections. If we set .serializeNulls()
>   gson replaces empty collections by "null".

No, Gson does not ignore ***empty collections*** even `serializeNulls` is set or not. ***null collections*** are ignored if `serializeNulls` is not set.

Below is an ***empty collection***:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

with or without `serializeNulls()`; json output is `{"list":[]}`

and below is a ***null collection***:

```
List list; // or List list = null;
```

with `serializeNulls()`; json output is `{"list":null}` but without `serializeNulls()`; json output is `{}`

> But best practice is to send [](empty collection) not null.

Yes, and that is what Gson does.

But if you want to send ***null collections*** like ***empty collections***, you can write a custom [TypeAdapter](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html).